# How do I convert Json object to a Java object dynamically

Tags: java, json

Here is my use case:

I have these classes on the serverside.

```
class Individual {
  protected String uri;
  protected int id;
}

class Person extends Individual {
  // Person properties like names, address etc
  String type = "Person";
}

class Role extends Individual {
  // Role properties like name, title etc
  String type = "Role";
}

class Organization extends Individual {
  // Org properties like name name, address etc
  String type = "Organization";
}
```

I have a class say `Action` like below.

```
class Action {
  String performedBy; // This can be any Individual
}
```

I have a controller that accepts an `Action`. I want the `Individual` to be correctly assigned depending on what the client sends. How should my `Action` & other classes be defined to achieve this?

if I send the following, I want `performedBy` to be a `Person`.

```
{
 "id": 10,
 "uri":"uri_blah",
 "lastname": "last_name",
 "type":"Person"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `@JsonType` annotation which allows to serialize the type into property:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
   use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
   include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
   property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
   @Type(value = Person.class, name = "Person"), 
   @Type(value = Role.class, name = "Role") 
   // ...
 })
 public abstract class Individual {
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: This answer is very useful, but unfortunately I can't give you +1 yet, cheers